# Resource-efficiency of Lubuntu-KDE combination

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, kde

I came up with the above combination in the bid to have the resource efficieny of Lubuntu, while having the familiarity of a windows-like environment of KDE. Prior to this, i started out with Unity on Ubuntu 16.04, which I tried to maximize by venturing into the latest Lubuntu-LXDE, and then on to Lubuntu-KDE. For now, I'm hard-pressed to point out any major flaw (just one unrelated, minor: sticky-notes is spawning post-its on my desktop). Overall, KSysGuard shows nothing remiss: no hardware issues; unsurprising slight lags when saving large docs; "mission-control/workspace" toggle is sharp, among others.

With minor edits: My concerns are: will such a setup (which may also be uninformed; its the result of dualbooting my formerly win7-only laptop, banking on my 1 year-experience of self-study Ubuntu) result to long-run problems? Specifically, if I want Lubuntu, should i purely stick to lxde; or if want kubuntu, should I stick to kde? Last, if i do want to observe for issues, will checking the resource monitor be enough? For now, I really want to keep this Lubuntu+KDE setup.

Comment: Lubuntu+KDE? So that's all the bloat of Kubuntu, and none of the lightness of Lubuntu?

Comment: @muru, it realy seems light on resources already, with no hint of bloat. Its just that I want to learn ahead if this setup is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

LXDE is designed for speed and resource efficiency (see [LXDE home page](http://lxde.org/)), and is ***the*** reason that Lubuntu is lighter and faster than just plain Ubuntu.

Switching to KDE will slow the system down and defeats the object. If you have a decent CPU and lots of RAM then you shouldn't notice a difference, but if that's the case then you might as well run GNOME or UNITY instead.

I'm running Lubuntu/LXDE on an old Pentium M 1.86 Ghz processor with 2GB RAM and it's ***fast***.